# clone a datatable row with control in it

Tags: jquery, datatables, clone

I have datatablejs table setup with each row having input, select control in it. I want to copy/clone a row , so that values of each control copied to new row.

```
var myTr = $(obj).closest('tr');
var clone = myTr.clone();

myTr.after(clone);
```

the above code do clone the row, but its not  part of datatable, any event like search or sorting or page change remove the cloned row, how to make the cloned row part of the table?

Comment: table populate using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Avoid direct manipulation of the table and use [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) DataTables API method to add a new row instead of jQuery `after()` method. This API method accepts DOM node or jQuery object as an argument.

For example:

```
var $newRow = $row.clone();
$('#example').DataTable().row.add($newRow).draw();
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/nfsotvj4/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my problem is , as i narrated above, i have controls in each column <input type='text'> <select> etc , they don't get copied , i get reply like

Comment: <input type=     Copy | Delete" name="budget_node_id[]"> Copy | Copy | Delete);" href="javascript:;">Delete